# $\forall a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ prove that $(a-b)(c-d)+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c) \geq 0$ and $a + d = b + c$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math

$\forall a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ prove that $(a-b)(c-d)+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c)$ and
$a + d = b + c$
*Attempt*

consider $(a-b)(c-d)+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c)=2(a-b)(c-d)$ since $2 >0$ we also want show that
$(a-b)(c-d)\geq 0$

When $a=c$ or $c=d$ we get that the expression can be $0$. Otherwise

Suppose that
$(a-b)(c-d)<0$ for $a,b,c,d$ it implies that the expression is  upper bounded by $0$
but for $a=1,b=-1,c=3,d=1$ it not occur therefore must be $(a-b)(c-d) \geq 0$.

I don´t sure of the part above, is mi proof right?
or I should consider an argue of say that
for real numbers $a,b,c,d$ we have that if $(a-b)<0$ then $(c-d)$ cannot be $(c-d)>0$ and similary in the other cases. Argue that we cannot have two factors with differnt sign.

Thanks in advice, I appreciate any hint or correction.

Comment: The inequality doesn't seem to be true for all $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider $a=d=0$, $b=c=1$. In fact, since you have already identified that the expression is equal to $2(a-b)(c-d)$, you can see that whenever $a<b$ and $c>d$, or $a>b$ and $c<d$, the inequality won't be satisfied.

Comment: I think theres a missing hypothesis that $a + d = b + c$. This problem is in the first section of "Inequalities: A mathematical olympiad approach," where it's cited as coming from (Czech and Slovak Republics, 2004)

Comment: You should argue for all reals ,your proof is not correct

Comment: with the new information of the problem i get confused, because for come to equalty $2(a-b)(c-d)$ I only use basic algebra and is equivalent expression, but the new information say $a+d=b+c$ which implies $a-b=c-d$ and it $4(a-b)$ from here is not secure since $a>b$ makes positive and $a<b$ makes negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a+d=b+c \Rightarrow a-b=c-d$
$$(a-b)(c-d)+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c)=(a-b)^2+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c)$$
Notice that $$(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c)=ab-ad-cb+dc+db-dc-ab+ac$$
$$=ac-ad+db-cb$$
$$=a(c-d)+b(d-c)=a(c-d)-b(c-d)=(a-b)^2$$
Remplazing

$$(a-b)^2+(a-b)^2=2(a-b)^2 \geq 0$$ which is true